# How does jetty SSL works with java key store and multiple aliases

Tags: java, ssl, jetty, jks, jsse

In the SSL Configuration of jetty, I see that we define the password of the keystore and the keystore physical location.

But what happens when I have multiple aliases on the keystore ? What keystore does jetty SSL  chooses to use ?

In my java keystore file, one alias hold untrusted certificates and one alias is trusted. How can i tell jetty to use the trusted alias ?

Thanks

Comment: There is no such thing as Jetty SSL. It uses the JSSE built in to Java.

Comment: The implementation of the ssl related code is made in jetty. In jsse specs they dont mention alias.

Comment: And are you asking about multiple aliases in one keystore, or multiple keystores, or multiple aliases in multiple keystores? And why do you have untrusted certificates in your keystore? or anywhere else? Your question remains obscure.

Comment: A jks can hold many aliases. Which is chosen ? The certs are now trusted. And my jks contain only 1 issued and valid certs. The question is still relevant.

Comment: If your KeyStore only contains one issued certificate there is only one alias to use. Unclear what you're asking. Still.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to configure the CertAlias attribute in jetty-ssl-context.xml.

```
<Configure id="sslContextFactory" class="org.eclipse.jetty.util.ssl.SslContextFactory">
   ...
  <Set name="CertAlias"><Property name="jetty.keystore.alias" default="localhost"/></Set>
</Configure>
```